# Got error after I try to open a workflow task: This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service

Tags: workflow, tasks

I am using sharepoint 2013. I have builded a workflow. Inside this workflow I have a task. This task will be assigned to some sharepoint group. When I start this workflow I can see the created created task. The task is assigned to me so I have the permissions to open it. The task is created under impersonate. When I try to open the task I got this error:

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of
>   the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information,
>   contact your server administrator.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the Server State Service in the SharePoint Wizard in central admin. It wasnt yet installed!